# Is there a way to assign to variables like this at the same time?

Tags: python

```
source_stream_offsets[1] = vertex_count * 0x10
source_stream_offsets[-1] = vertex_count * 0x10 + sum(source_stream_offsets[:-1])
```

Is there a way to shorten this code to assign both variables at once? I want to do something similar to:

```
variable_a, variable_b = 1, 2
```

However, the second variable assigned is dependent on the first variable assigned. How can I make this more compact? Are there any ways of doing so?

Comment: You cannot assign them "at once" if you need to know one value before being able to calculate the other.

Comment: You could replace `vertex_count * 0x10` with `source_stream_offsets[1]` to avoid calculating the same thing twice.

Comment: Why do you `sum()` a `list` with only one element (`source_stream_offsets[:-1]`)?

Comment: It doesn't just have one element. It's an ndarray with multiple offsets. I change the first offset which moves the rest of the offsets which is why I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of `source_stream_offsets` (I assume here it is a list), you could just slice and unpack the original object and make a new one using the following one-liner. Please mind that I have abbreviated the name of the original object to `sso`:

```
sso = [vertex_count * 0x10, *sso[1:-1], vertex_count * 0x10 + sum(sso[:-1])]
```

If the object is of different type, e.g.: numpy ndarray, you can just convert the list back to the desired type. However, numpy arrays allow also assigning to multiple indices using the following syntax, which does not require unpacking and packing back:

```
sso[(0,-1),] = vertex_count * 0x10, vertex_count * 0x10 + sum(sso[:-1])
```

In my honest opinion both these options are far less readable and I am not sure whether they achieve the desired goal as @matszwecja noticed, but they technically assigns both variables at once.

Comment: This doesn't work because it's a numpy array and not a list.

Comment: You did not specify that the object is a numpy array. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there not a way to keep it as a numpy array without having to convert it? Also, is it less efficient to convert it to a list and back to an array? Or does that not matter?

Comment: It definitely is less efficient to convert back and forth this way. If it does matter of not depends on where do you use this code and if it takes a lot of time to begin with.

Comment: I have updated the answer specifically for numpy arrays.

Comment: @3qxs7na6, if the answer satisfies you, please mark it as accepted; otherwise please provide additional details.